# How to sample from data given criterions, permutation methods

Tags: r, permutation, sampling

I'm performing permutations on my data by using sample() and loops.

I have data for 400 cases and 1000 controls from 90 hospitals. I have ran a logistic regression for this data. Now I want to do permutations.

My plan is to:

1) Randomly select a 'case' from ANY hospital

2) Randomly select a 'control' from a DIFFERENT hospital

3) Repeat steps 1 & 2 until I have 90 different cases and 90 different controls. The aim is that each hospital with have one case OR one control.

This is my code so far:

```
CaseControl<-as.factor(c(rep(1,400), rep(0,1000)))
Hospital<-c(rep(1:90, 15), rep(1:50))
DataFrame<-data.frame(CaseControl, Hospital)
Case<-data.frame(subset(DataFrame,CaseControl=="0"))
Control<-data.frame(subset(DataFrame,CaseControl=="1"))

PermutedDataset<-matrix(,180,2)
RCase<-matrix(,90,2)
RControl<-matrix(,90,2)

RCase[1,]<-as.matrix(Case[sample(nrow(Case),1),])
RControl[1,]<-as.matrix(Control[ sample( which( Control$Hospital != RCase[1,2] ) , 1 ) , ])

RCase[2,]<- as.matrix(Case[ sample( which( Case$Hospital != RCase[1,2] ) , 1),])
RControl[2,]<-as.matrix(Control[ sample(  which( Control$Hospital != RCase[2,2] & Control$Hospital != RControl[1,2] ) , 1),])

for (i in 3:90) {
RCase[i,]<- as.matrix(Case[ sample(  which( Case$Hospital != RCase[1:i-1,2])   , 1),])
RControl[i,]<-as.matrix(Control[ sample(  which( Control$Hospital != RCase[i,2] & Control$Hospital != RControl[1:i-1,2]) , 1),])

}
```

My code runs, however I am getting repeated hospital IDs from the loop section. I have stated to sample only from the data where hospital ID is not equal to any previous Hospital IDs already sampled.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Wouldn't `sample(Control$Hospital, 90, replace = F)` and 
`sample(Case$Hospital, 90, replace = F)` be sufficient to randomly select 90 controls and cases?

Comment: I think the problem is `RCase[1:i-1, 2]`, try `1:10-1` in your console to see the output. Maybe fixing that by adding parenthesis 1:(i-1) will make the duplicate IDs disappear.

Comment: @josemz I think you're right, I've tried using 1:(i-1) and seq(1,(i-1)), however I still get duplicate Hospital IDs in the output. Is there another way I could write this part of the code?

Comment: @NM_ The problem with this is that duplicate case/controls occur within the sample. I need to set constraints such that once a case is chosen, that individual can't be chosen again, nor that hospital ID. The same then applies for controls.